How to use AD groups in IDM?
I would like to use AD groups in IdM. I have configured AD trust with:
Trust direction: Trusting forest
Trust type: Non-transitive external trust to a domain in another Active Directory forest

For example, I have IDM group docker, with one IDM account, jenkins. That is related with system docker group, to use docker command on OS.
It works with jenkins account but does not work with AD group. The command getent group docker returns only jenkins account assigned to that group. While getent group AD_group returns proper AD members. The AD_group group is added to IDM as external.
Is this possible? I want manage those groups only for IDM's accounts. I can add external member to external group but this is not the way.

Based on https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/active-directory-trust#trust-win-groups

Group membership in the IdM LDAP is expressed by specifying a distinguished name (DN) of an LDAP object that is a member of a group. AD entries are not synchronized or copied over to IdM, which means that AD users and groups have no LDAP objects in the IdM LDAP. Therefore, they cannot be directly used to express group membership in the IdM LDAP.
For this reason, IdM creates non-POSIX external groups: proxy LDAP objects that contain references to SIDs of AD users and groups as strings. Non-POSIX external groups are then referenced as normal IdM LDAP objects to signify group membership for AD users and groups in IdM.

